# How to change the focus order in a custom panel with keyboard navigation?

Tags: wpf, focus, panel

I have a custom panel with some items. When one item has the focus and I want to navigate to the next item by pressing the right arrow, the focus jumps to the **nearest** item to the right. However, I want the focus to move to **another** item, determined by my own logic. How can I change the focus order?

Answer (score -1):

[Check it](http://www.julmar.com/blog/mark/PermaLink,guid,6e4769e5-a0b3-47b2-a142-6dfefd0c028e.aspx), this can be helpful:

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. I can't see a way to persuade the FocusManager to change its behavior.